# menu fixo com jquery em determinada rolagem (scroll) da página

Tags: jquery, menu, rolamento

Estou tentando deixar este menu fixo https://jsfiddle.net/40ouwkcw/  a partir de determinada rolagem da página, neste caso, após a imagem inicial. 
   Encontrei vários tutoriais no google, mas nenhum funciona no menu. Eu até tentei os perguntados aqui e também nada.

> É difícil achar um menu igual o meu, e a maioria dos tutoriais são
>   pra menus que comecem dentro de uma nav mas o meu começa em uma div
>   talvez isso esteja influenciando em algo.

Enfim. Se puderem dá uma olhada e me ajudarem, ou me indicarem um site com um tutorial que você ache que vai se adequar ao meu, agradeço, pois todos que tentei não funcionaram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, faça assim:

Adicione um identificador à sua `<img>`:

HTML

```
<img class="imgTopo" src='https://static.cineclick.com.br/sites/adm/uploads/banco_imagens/31/602x0_1439644246.jpg'/>
```

Criamos em CSS propriedades para uma classe que a `#navbar` vai ter quando o scroll for abaixo da imagem:

```
.fixed-menu {
   position:fixed;
   background:red;
   width:100% !important;
   z-index:9999;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}
```

E por fim JQUERY:

```
(function($, sr) {

     alturaImg = $('.imgTopo').height(); // altura da imagem, vai servir para sabermos a altura que o scroll tem de andar até a navbar ficar fixa
     $(window).on('scroll', function() { // cada vez de que fizer scroll o que está dentro desta função vai acontecer
          if($(window).scrollTop() >= alturaImg) { // se o que percorremos com o scroll for maior ou igual à altura da imagem adicionamos esta classe à navbar
              $('#navbar').addClass('fixed-menu');
          }
          else {
              $('#navbar').removeClass('fixed-menu');
          }
     });
....
```

Usando o seu exemplo, [aqui está o jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40ouwkcw/4/)

Comment: me desculpe mas eu não expliquei direito, eu mudei o link lá em cima, porque eu deveria ter colado alguma foto antes do menu, porque eu quero que ao passar por essa foto, o menu fique fixo.