# Menu fixo após rolagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Quero fazer o menu ficar fixo após certa rolagem,

```
 <script>
    $("document").ready(function($){
        var nav = $('.menu-topo');

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
                nav.addClass("fixo");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("fixo");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

e o html

```
<div id="menu-topo">asdasdasd</div>
```

Não está ficando fixo. O que está errado?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [menu fixo com jquery em determinada rolagem (scroll) da página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129367/menu-fixo-com-jquery-em-determinada-rolagem-scroll-da-p%c3%a1gina)

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando `menu-topo` como id e no seletor está procurando pela classe `.menu-topo` em vez de `#menu-topo`.

Comment: A variável `nav` ali é um objeto jquery de length 0. Verificar a length antes de continuar desenvolvendo é interessante pra não acontecer esse tipo de erro.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma maneira muito mais fácil e simples de fazer isso usando apenas uma propriedade do css chamada `Position: sticky`.

```
div.sticky {
   position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   padding: 5px;
   background-color: #cae8ca;
   border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

<div class="sticky">MENU</div>
```

Comment: Não rolou essa manha, tentei aqui e nada.